# How to get unique ID From Recycleview with onclicklistener in Android

Tags: java, android

My items are fetching information from database and showing the list in recycleview.
I want to get the unique id by clicking the each.How can I get it?Here is my code of Myadapter class and the java activity where I have worked on to show the user details.

My Code:
MyAdapter.class:

```
package com.example.bookingapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<User> list;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        User user = list.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(user.getname());
        holder.email.setText(user.getemail());
        holder.phone.setText(user.getphone());
        holder.specialization.setText(user.getSpecialization());
       

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public View mView;
        TextView name, email, phone, specialization;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvemail);
            phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);
            specialization = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvspecialization);


        }


    }
}
```

list:

```
package com.example.bookingapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;



        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

        import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Doctorslist extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference database;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctorslist);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userList);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Doctors");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    list.add(user);


                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

I tried with this code in MyAdapter.java 's onBindViewHolder but it shows error

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyAdapter.this,RegisterPatientActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userKey",getRef(position).getKey().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solved my own question just by reconstructing my code.

**1. In the adapter class, I created an interface for itemClickListener**

> ```
> public interface RecyclerViewItemClick {
>
>     public void OnItemClickListener(UsersViewHolders holder, int position);
>
> }
> ```

**and create a global**

> private RecyclerViewItemClick mListener;

**add it to constructor**

```
 public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User>list,RecyclerViewItemClick listener) {
         this.context = context;
         this.list = list;
         this.mListener = listener;
     }
```

**2. In onBindViewHolder() I passed the holder and the position**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mListener.OnItemClickListener(holder, position);

        }

    });
}
```

**3. In your activity, add this code. Declare a global variable for ArrayList to store the keys and call the addListenerForSingleValueEvent to your DatabaseReference**

```
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

                 String uid = datas.getKey();

                //mUserKey is an ArrayList<String>
                mUserKey.add(uid);

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                list.add(user);


                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

**4. Now add this to get the key for every position**

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(new MyAdapter.RecyclerViewItemClick() {

        @Override
        public void OnItemClickListener(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            String userKey = mUserKey.get(position);

            //do you job

        }

    });
```